# Linkedin Api Saved Jobs

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

is there a way to retrieve my linkedin saved jobs from the API without registering for the partnership program? (And if not, can I do it by registering?)

Answer (score 1):

you can use linkedin Api console to get the basics of what data you can get.

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

for your question you just need to add "positions" field to your query in order to get saved jobs.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url,positions)?format=json